# Create adjacency matrix from matrix with indices

Tags: r, matrix

I currently have a matrix that looks as follows:

```
          [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
    [1,]     2    12    NA    NA    NA    NA
    [2,]     1     3     7    13    NA    NA
    [3,]     2     4     8    14    NA    NA
    [4,]     3     5     9    15    NA    NA
    ....
    ....
    ....
    [31870] ....                       .....
```

What I want to do, is create an adjacency matrix of size 31870 x 31870. The first row of this new matrix would consist of only zeroes, except for ones at columns 2 and 12. And so forth for the other rows. Ideally the solution is both quick, flexible enough to handle larger more than 6 neighbors, and can also be applied to create matrices of other dimensionality than 31870 x 31870.

Online I found references to the ifelse() function, but I was not able to implement it correctly. I also tried looping through an empty binary matrix. That did not work either. I also tried looking up similar probelms with the keywords 'binary matrix', 'design matrix', and 'adjacency matrix'. I attempted converting my matrix to an edge list, and then turning it into an adjacency matrix. I did not get it to work.

**Update**

I ended up solving the problem with the following nested for-loops and the igraph-package:

```r
# Count the non-NaNs in the matrix
nr_of_entries_adjacencies <- dim(matrix)[1] * dim(matrix)[2]

# Initialize an empty matrix to store all adjacencies
init_edge_list <- matrix(data = NaN, nrow = nr_of_entries_adjacencies, ncol = 2) 

# My original problem was concerned with finding the number of neighbors to a coordinate. 
#Here I added one extra 'neighbor', which represents the coordinate's distance to itself

nr_of_neighbors_plus_one <- 7

for (row_nr in 1:dim(matrix)[1]) {
  print(row_nr)
  for (col_nr in 1:dim(matrix)[2]) {
    if (is.na(matrix[row_nr,col_nr]) == FALSE) {
      edge_list_row_nr <- ((row_nr-1) * nr_of_neighbors_plus_one) + col_nr
      init_edge_list[edge_list_row_nr ,2] <- init_row_nan_padded[row_nr, col_nr]
      init_edge_list[edge_list_row_nr, 1] <- row_nr
    }
  }
}

 # Remove the rows with Na's
edge_list <- na.omit(init_edge_list)

# Convert to graph dataframe
graph_dataframe <- igraph::graph.data.frame(edge_list)

# Convert to adjacency matrix
adjacency_matrix <- igraph::get.adjacency(graph_dataframe,sparse=TRUE)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is what Chat GPT answered for your question! It is amazing!!!

Here's an efficient and concise code using `apply()` and `which()` functions:

```
# Create an empty adjacency matrix
adjacency_matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(matrix), ncol = ncol(matrix))

# Iterate through each row of your matrix and get the non-NA values
neighbors <- apply(matrix, 1, function(x) which(!is.na(x)))

# Set the corresponding elements in the adjacency matrix to 1
adjacency_matrix[cbind(1:nrow(matrix), neighbors)] <- 1
```

This code will accomplish the same task as the previous example, but in a more efficient and concise way. The `apply()` function is used to iterate through each row of the matrix and the `which()` function is used to find the non-NA values. The result of the `apply()` function is a list of vectors, where each vector contains the indices of the non-NA values for each row. This list is then used to set the corresponding elements in the adjacency matrix to 1 using the `cbind()` function.

This code will work for any size of matrix, you just need to change the input matrix.

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure about the last line? It starts throwing the following error: Error in adjacency_matrix[cbind(1:nrow(matrix), neighbors)] <- 1 : 
  invalid subscript type 'list'